# How to use Inner Join and then fill a DataSet with result of the join?

Tags: c#, database, join

Well, this is my question. In short terms; I have two tables, Consequents and Atomic propositions:

AtomicP table

```
 ID        Proposition  
    1     | A              | 
    1     | B              | 
    1     | C              |   
    2     | D              | 
    2     | E              |
```

Consequent Table

```
ID    |  Consequent    | 
1     | A              | 
2     | B              |
```

And all I just want to do, is to  implement a inner join which gives me all the values where the ID for  both tables is the same(i.e):

```
AtomicP Table  "A"   "B"   "C" -> "A" Consequent Table
```

and withe result given tanks to the inner joins , save that result in a Data Set or in another data structure that could be better.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the destination table has the values Id, Proposition and Consequent ..

```
insert into newtable (id,proposition,consequent) select id,atomicP,Consequent from atmicp,consequent where atomicP.id = consequent.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Proposition
{
    public int Id;
    public string Value;

    public Proposition(int id, string value){
       Id = id;
       Value = value;
    }
}

public class Consequent
{
   public int Id;
   public string Value;

   public Consequent(int id, string value){
     Id = id;
     Value = value;
   }
}

var atomicP = new List<Proposition>{
   new Proposition(1, "A"),
   new Proposition(1, "B"),
   new Proposition(1, "C"),
   new Proposition(2, "D"),
   new Proposition(2, "E"),
}

var consequents = new List<Consequent>{
   new Consequent(1, "A"),
   new Consequent(2, "B"),
}

var query = from proposition in atomicP
            join consequent in consequents on proposition.Id == consequent.Id
            select proposition.Value;

return query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function

```
private DataTable JoinDataTables(DataTable t1, DataTable t2, params Func<DataRow, DataRow, bool>[] joinOn)
{
    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataColumn col in t1.Columns)
    {
        if (result.Columns[col.ColumnName] == null)
            result.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
    }
    foreach (DataColumn col in t2.Columns)
    {
        if (result.Columns[col.ColumnName] == null)
            result.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
    }
    foreach (DataRow row1 in t1.Rows)
    {
        var joinRows = t2.AsEnumerable().Where(row2 =>
            {
                foreach (var parameter in joinOn)
                {
                    if (!parameter(row1, row2)) return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
        foreach (DataRow fromRow in joinRows)
        {
            DataRow insertRow = result.NewRow();
            foreach (DataColumn col1 in t1.Columns)
            {
                insertRow[col1.ColumnName] = row1[col1.ColumnName];
            }
            foreach (DataColumn col2 in t2.Columns)
            {
                insertRow[col2.ColumnName] = fromRow[col2.ColumnName];
            }
            result.Rows.Add(insertRow);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

An example of how you might use this:

```
var test = JoinDataTables(Consequents, Atomic,
               (row1, row2) =>
               row1.Field<int>("ID") == row2.Field<int>("ID"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to join In C# and get `DataTable`(bit unclear in question).

Code snippets joins two `DataTable` using `Linq` and inserts to another Table.

```
DataTable results = new DataTable();
results.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
results.Columns.Add("Proposition", typeof(string));
results.Columns.Add("Consequent", typeof(string));

var result1 = from arow in AtomicP.AsEnumerable()
    join con in Consequent.AsEnumerable()
    on arow.Field<int>("ID") equals con.Field<int>("ID")
    select results.LoadDataRow(new object[]
                               {
                                   arow.Field<int>("ID"),
                                   arow.Field<string>("Proposition"),
                                   con.Field<string>("Consequent")
                               }, false);
```

Now we can access results by iterating through results.

```
foreach(DataRow row in results.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataColumn column in results.Columns)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
    }
}
```

Working [`Code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uiumnk)

Comment: thank you! :) that's what I need. and I have other question , how would you iterate over the new table?

Comment: @superkiller170793 included iteration code snippet.

Comment: @superkiller170793 Please take time to upvote and mark this as answer if it helped you and is the answer to the question.